# Ignore field in mapper without related property in mapped object

Tags: java, mapstruct

can you tell me how ignore some field which doesn't have related property in another object?

I have Foo and FooDto objects and I want mapper for them. In Dto object I got another property `boolean isFoo` which isn't in Foo object.

I tried somethink like that:

```
@Mapper
public interface FooMapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "isFoo", ignore = true)
    })
    FooDto doToDto(Foo foo);

    Foo dtoToDo(FooDto fooDto);
}
```

and I got error

> Unknown property "isFoo" in result type FooDto.

What I do wrong? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct is not looking into the name of the fields to find their names. It uses the JavaBeans specification. Have a look more in [Basic Mappings](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#basic-mappings).

I suppose that you have a method called `isFoo()` in `FooDto` in this case the name of the property is `foo`. So you would need to do `@Mapping(target = "foo", ignore = true)`

Answer (score 0):

That means that mapper is trying to link `FooDto.isFoo` with `Foo.isFoo` but it doesn't exist on `FooDto`. This will potentially cause you to lose data as `isFoo` won't be set on `Foo` entity, so I would strongly recommend to add this field on the DTO class. If you really don't want to add new filed, you need to add another mapping above `Foo dtoToDo(FooDto fooDto)` to ignore this filed.

Comment: Can you show me please what do you mean with another mapping? I googled a lot but I didn't found any which should solve my problem.

Comment: This field is used only in DTO because I need it in service class to do some computing. In domain entity in database I don't need it.